# Calculating chi-square and p-value

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, p-value

I'd like to test people's preference on model A against three other models B,C,D.

I asked 5000 people on crowd sourcing to rate all 4 models (thus, there are 20,000 ratings overall) in the scale of 1 to 5.

I've grouped the results into 3 categories, which are 1) model A won, 2) model A lost, and 3) model A and compared model received equal rating. Results are as following:

```
compared model  | A won |  equal  | A lost
B                  2208    1222     1570
C                  2970    538      1492
D                  1890    1454      1656
```

I calculated chi-square with 2 degrees of DOF, with expected value as 2,000 for winning and losing, and 1,000 for par, and got chi-squares of 133.37, 812.93, 271.33 for each comparison.

Is my calculation correct? And if so, most online calculators simply return "p-value is less than 0.000001", but is there a way to get specific p-values from  chi-squares, however small they may be? Also, since chi-squares are very high and p-values very small (if correct), does it mean that the results are statistically significant?

======edit=======

Null hypothesis is that "all models are equally preferred".

Alternative hypothesis obviously is that model A is better.

========edit=====

I grouped the results into 3 categories, because each worker has a different range of ratings. For example, worker A may give 5 to good models, and 1 to bad models, while worker B may give 3 to good models and 2 to bad models, etc. Thus, std. dev turned out to be pretty large (over +/- 1.0) and I needed to simplify the results to figure out the significance.

Comment: It's not clear what the null and alternative hypotheses are here

Comment: If the question is whether or not the distribution is the same across rows, no, it's not. At all. I get a $\chi^2$ around 700 on 4 degrees of freedom.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing 3 Chi-Squared goodness of fit tests against the distribution 2000, 1000, 2000. If so, I'm not sure what numbers you are comparing to but in any case such an approach is not a sensible test of your stated hypotheses. If you are only interested in whether A is better, I would suggest using the rank data rather than categories and looking into Superiority testing (e.g., http://hjdbulletin.org/files/archive/pdfs/431.pdf)

Comment: Your null hypothesis is not sufficiently specific to conduct a test.  If it were modified to "all models are equally preferred," that would imply equal rates of preferences. The basis of choosing 2000 and 1000 in your table is obscure: it does not appear to be deducible from your incomplete hypothesis.

Comment: You say you have data from 5,000 people, but the frequencies add up to more than 5,000.  Please explain your data more fully.

Comment: Why did you group the data from your 5 point scale into 3 categories? That is likely to reduce the power of your test.

Comment: it's premature to place a bounty on a question that has many issues that remain unclear. It might draw an answer but answers to unclear questions may be unhelpful or even lead you away from a suitable understanding.

Comment: @Glen_b sorry for late response + unclear parts. I've edited the question as best as I can to reflect the comments. I will greatly appreciate it if someone could help me figure this out.

Comment: You need to clarify still. The alternative to your stated null hypothesis is that not all ratings are equal which doesn't tell you directly whether A is preferred. If you are interested in only in the superiority of A, you can test 3 null-hypotheses, A=B, A=C, A=D, with 3 alternative hypotheses that would depend on whether 5 is a good or bad rating. Note, however, that failing to find a significant difference does not constitute evidence that no difference exists (see: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2550545/pdf/bmj00606-0027.pdf). Consider superiority testing mentioned above

Comment: As to your concern about differing individual rating ranges, statistical tests are generally designed to deal with just that sort of variability. Further, as you seem to have repeated measures data, that variability is even less of a concern as that variability is generally accounted for by the test. I can only speak in general here because I don't yet fully understand what you're after. However, I'm fairly certain your categorizing scheme is incoherent and does not address your concern correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your use of a chisquare test is inappropriate. One problem is that the same 5000 people appear more than once in your table, so the counts are not independent. Another problem is the use of arbitrarily chosen expected values.

One simple and correct way to test your hypotheses is to compare A with each of the other models one at a time. Comparing A to B, your table shows that 2208 people prefer A and 1570 prefer B. An exact one-sided p-value can be obtained from the binomial probability in R:

pbinom(2208-0.5, prob=0.5, size=2208+1570, lower.tail=FALSE)

which is 1.4e-25. This tests the null hypothesis that people are equally likely to prefer A or B vs the alternative that people are more likely to prefer A. The binomial test conditions on the total number of people who had a preference.

Comparing A to C gives:

pbinom(2970-0.5, prob=0.5, size=2970+1492, lower.tail=FALSE)

which is 1.1e-110. Comparing A to D gives:

pbinom(1890-0.5, prob=0.5, size=1890+1656, lower.tail=FALSE)

which is 4.5e-05.

So, yes, there is strong evidence that the respondents tend to prefer model A over each of the other three alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to get specific p-values from chi-squares?

Yes. In R use `1-pchisq()`, for example `1-pchisq(133.37,2)` is 0. This is because the number is so small, R rounds it to 0.

> Also, since chi-squares are very high and p-values very small (if correct), does it mean that the results are statistically significant?

Yes. A rule of thumb provided by Ronald Fisher is that if the p-value is less than 5% (0.05) then the result is significant.

> Is my calculation correct?

I wouldn't have calculated it like this:

1. Start by plotting the percentage of ratings for each model side-by-side
2. Compare the shapes using a chi-square test, i.e. A vs. B, A vs. B, A vs. C. To do this, treat the A count as being the observed data, and the B data as being expected. Note the degrees of freedom would change to 5, therefore you use a chi-square(4) distribution

Some pseudo-code for point 2 in R is:

```
A = 5000*c(0.2,0.3,0.5,0.3,0.2) # These are the proportions rating A as 1-5
B = 5000*c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2) # These are the proportions rating B as 1-5
TestStat = sum(((A-B)^2)/B) # Find the chi-square test statistic (2750)
PVal = 1-pchisq(TestStat,4) # Find the p-value (0), which is significant
```